# Weird Jquery mixitup plugin issues in Chrome - works only when run in dev console

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, webkit

No problems with Firefox.

I've tried implementing the mixitup jquery plugin (https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com) in my code, and it does not work (for me) in Chrome (or Opera, and probably other webkit browsers).

**The only time I can get it to work is when I run the code directly in Chrome's console.**

The code is nothing fancy:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.products').mixItUp({
        animation: {
            duration: 400,
            effects: 'fade translateZ(-360px) stagger(34ms)',
            easing: 'ease'
        },
        callbacks: {
            onMixStart: function(state, futureState){
                alert('Animation starting');
            },onMixLoad: function(state){
                alert('MixItUp ready!');
            },onMixEnd: function(state){
                alert('Operation ended');
            },onMixFail: function(state){
                alert('No elements found matching '+state.activeFilter);
            },onMixBusy: function(state){
                alert('MixItUp busy');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The only callback that shows in Chrome (except when run in Chrome's Console) is the "Animation starting". They should all show (which they do when run in Chrome's Console).

I've tried putting it in both $(window).load(function() { and "document ready" code too, which didn't make any difference.

I've also tried moving the code from the header area to just before `</body>` and that makes no difference either - no surprises.

I am running out of ideas as to why it works in Chrome's Console, but not in the JS file or inline, before the `</body>`. Again Firefox seems to have no issues.

This is doing my head in.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the support forums? https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/support/

Comment: You should provide your html as well, Is the list of products static or loaded from server async call?